How can I reset the numbering value of a list to 1 in Slack?

In a Slack message, I create two ordered lists that each start at 1.
For example:
Done:
1. Item_A1
2. Item_A2
3. Item_A3

Todo:
1. Item_B1
2. Item_B2
3. Item_B3
4. Item_B4


The lists look correct while editing the message:


But, after saving the message, the second list is renumbered with the numbering from the first list.
Done:
1. Item_A1
2. Item_A2
3. Item_A3

Todo:
4. Item_B1
5. Item_B2
6. Item_B3
7. Item_B4




How can I make the second list start from 1 as well?

I think you are out of luck. It seems to be a bug when the list is rendered.
